# iPhone: How to find the duration of the album video?

Tags: iphone

I am picking video from photo album programmatically. I don't have any issues on that. I am able to retrieve the video path etc from the following delegate method.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

But, i want to find out the duration of the video here. Is it possible to find out the duration of that video which i have chosen from photo album?

Please advise!

Thank you!

Comment: This link has helped me resolving this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699105/iphone-how-to-get-duration-of-video-selected-from-library